# Date format and calendar widget for site analytics page don't use site locale

Tags: bug, localization, dates, site-analytics, calendar

There are US date format and calendar for [site analytics page on StackOverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) (I'm guessing that the same exist for other non-English StackExchange sites but I don't have 25k reputation score to check that)

> [image: us analytics]

At the same time calendar widget is completely localized when accessed from the user profile page section:

> [image: ru profile page]